# CardView design changes when moved inside layout data

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-databinding, android-cardview

I used data layout for my CardView, it was looking good until moved inside data layout for data binding.
Here is how it looked before layout data and data binding:

[image]

here is how it looked after data layout

[image]

here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >

    <data>
        <variable
            name="user"
            type="User" />
    </data>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:usernameOnClick="@{user.username}"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:cardElevation="6dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp">

          --- Some content for avatar view and text ---


        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</layout>
```

here is the code to use data binding

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): UserViewHolder {
        val binding = ItemUserBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context))
        return UserViewHolder(binding)
    }

 class UserViewHolder(var binding: ItemUserBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(user:User){
            binding.user=user
            }
        }
```

Also note that I tried to put CardView inside ConstraintLayout, it fixed the width but not the elevation

Comment: Ah, cool. Glad to hear. Sorry I'd deleted my comment there. I couldn't remember how `RecyclerView` handles `layout_margin` on its items, and wasn't sure if that was gonna fix everything for you. In any case, it's nothin' huge. :-) Please feel free to finish this up however you like. Thanks for the offer, though. I appreciate it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer thanks to [Mike M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2850651/mike-m) comment.
The problem is fixed by changing the inflate function call to the following

```
val binding = ItemUserBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
```